# Fluentd apache format [warn]: pattern not match:

Tags: apache, fluentd

In my /etc/fluent/fluent.conf

```
<source>
  @type tail
  format apache2
  path /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log
  tag apache2.access
</source>
```

> Error / warn : 2016-02-11 00:59:10 +0100 [warn]: pattern not match:
>   "mybebsite.dz:443 105.101.114.234 - - [11/Feb/2016:00:59:10 +0100]
>   \"POST /__es/_all/_search HTTP/1.1\" 200 794
>   \"https://mywebsite.net/\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64;
>   rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0\""

Why this patern dosn't match ?
Best.

Answer (score 1):

I have been facing **warn: pattern not match** in fluentd, and because of this my filter section was not working. And then I took this warning seriously and resolved this by creating a regex. So, my td-agent.conf is as follows:

```
 <source>
    @type tail
    format **/^([^ ]*) (?<host>[^ ]*) [^ ]* "(?<method>\S+) (?<path>[^ ]* +\S*)? (?<code>[^ ]*) (?<size>[^ ]*) (?: "(?<referer>[^\"]*)" "(?<agent>[^\"]*)")?/**
    path /var/log/apache2/access.log
    pos_file /var/log/td-agent/httpd.access.pos
    tag s3.apache.access
  </source>
  <filter **>
    @type grep
    <regexp>
      key path
      pattern \/aws\/project_launch\/view\/[\w\W]*
    </regexp>
  </filter>
  <match **>
    @type s3
    aws_key_id xxxxxx
    aws_sec_key xxxxxx
    s3_bucket bucketalifluentd
    s3_region eu-west-1
    path logs_viewshare/
    buffer_path /var/log/td-agent/buffer/s3
    time_slice_format %Y-%m-%d/%H
    time_slice_wait 2m
  </match>
```

Please note that, the apache2 logs may be different for you, because you have made a different configuration in **apache2.conf**. You can use [rubular](http://rubular.com/)

for creating regex in ruby, because fluentd/td-agent has been written in ruby.
After that you can view buffer that has collected your logs in directory **/var/log/td-agent/buffer/s3.xxx**

Comment: I've used rubular and pasted the resulting (working) expression) into td-agent.conf. However, running fluentd on Windows and reading a Linux Docker forwarded stdout still fails to parse.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that tail plugin does not support the format for apache log format "vhost_combined" but "combined". 
How about changing the apache configuration file as follows:

/etc/apache2/conf-available/other-vhosts-access-log.conf
Before:`CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/other_vhosts_access.log vhost_combined`

    (change **vhost_combined** to **combined**)
After:`CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/other_vhosts_access.log combined`