# [warn]: pattern not match error on fluentd forwarder

Tags: fluentd, efk

I have a fluentd forwarder which gives following error:

```
2018-02-08 13:07:05 +0000 [warn]: pattern not match: "192.168.6.121 - - [08/Feb/2018:18:37:05 +0530] \"POST /shorten HTTP/1.1\" 200 496 \"-\" \"-\" 6"
```

Following is the content of source block in td-agent.conf file

```
<source>
  @type tail
  path /var/log/xyz.log
  pos_file /var/log/td-agent/xyz.log.pos
  tag xyz.url
  format  /(?<host>[\S]) \[(?<timestamp>.+)\] "(?<method>[\S]+) (?<path>[\S]+) (?<http>[\S]+)" (?<respcode>[\S]+) (?<resptime>[\S]) "(?<un1>[\S])" "(?<agent>.+)" (?<un2>[\S])/
</source>
```

I have checked the regex by taking a sample log file on https://www.debuggex.com/

Do I really have to provide a regex? Can't I just tell fluentd to take complete log line as a raw message?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it is not an error, but only a warning and with that warning you can not be able use filter section or may be forwarder which you are trying to use. For more information about resolving this **pattern not match** warning, you can see the answer that has been already given.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53369449/7486447