# Fluentd logs is full of backslash and kibana doesn't show k8s pods logs

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, kubernetes, kibana, fluentd

I set up an EFK stack for gathering my different k8s pods logs based on [this tutorial](https://mherman.org/blog/logging-in-kubernetes-with-elasticsearch-Kibana-fluentd/) on a Microk8s single node cluster. Everything is up and working and I can connect kibanna to elasticsearch and see the indexes but in the discovery section of kibana there is no log related to my pods and there are kubelete logs.

When I checked the logs of fluentd I saw that it is full of backslashes:

```
2019-08-05 15:23:17 +0000 [warn]: #0 [in_tail_container_logs] pattern not match: "2019-08-05T17:23:10.167379794+02:00 stdout P 2019-08-05 15:23:10 +0000 [warn]: #0 [in_tail_container_logs] pattern not match: \"2019-08-05T17:23:07.09726655+02:00 stdout P 2019-08-05 15:23:07 +0000 [warn]: #0 [in_tail_container_logs] pattern not match: \\\"2019-08-05T17:23:04.433817307+02:00 stdout P 2019-08-05 15:23:04 +0000 [warn]: #0 [in_tail_container_logs] pattern not match: \\\\\\\"2019-08-05T17:22:52.546188522+02:00 stdout P 2019-08-05 15:22:52 +0000 [warn]: #0 [in_tail_container_logs] pattern not match: \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"2019-08-05T17:22:46.694679863+02:00 stdout F 
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong and where all those backslashes are coming from?

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, I'm going to provide [this solution](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd/issues/2407#issuecomment-747488004), which seems a lot more straight forward than anything else I've found:

```
env:
    - name: FLUENT_CONTAINER_TAIL_PARSER_TYPE
      value: /^(?<time>.+) (?<stream>stdout|stderr) [^ ]* (?<log>.*)$/
```

Just place that in the env variables underneath your `fluentd` YAML configuration.

Comment: I was using containerd instead of docker, so this solution worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you should check/try:

1. Check how your patterns are configured (ex: `td-agent.conf`, `fluent.conf`).
2. Test your format regex matching with [Fluentular](http://fluentular.herokuapp.com/) to see if there are any potential mistakes.
3. Consider using [fluent-plugin-multi-format-parser](https://github.com/repeatedly/fluent-plugin-multi-format-parser):
4. For more information about resolving similar `pattern not match` issue, you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53369449/7486447).

Please let me know if any of the above helped.